# aFileChoser in fragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

i made this example: [swipe tab](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

but i can't make the aFileChooser to work with fragmanactivity.
I added it as it has to, but cant get the result_ok int the onActivityresult.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHOOSER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                File file = FileUtils.getFile(uri);
                Log.e("", file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
        }
    }
```

How can i manage to get the RESUL_OK to work,because the eclipse said:
 `RESULT_OK cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: post the code in which you are starting file activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `RESULT_OK` with `Activity.RESULT_OK` then it will work..